# Argument of type "Literal[0]" cannot be assigned to parameter "__s" of type "slice"

Tags: python, pylance

I currently have this code in my assignment. The part `[[None]*(n+1) for i in range(m+1)]` is copied from the lecture. But for me its not working. For others the exact same code is working.

Edit: The code is working, but the error/ warning message is still bothering me.

```py
def fillDPtable(u, v):
    m = len(u)
    n = len(v)

    edelta = [[None]*(n+1) for i in range(m+1)]
    edelta[0][0] = 0

    for i in range(1, m+1):
        edelta[i][0] = edelta[i-1][0]+1
    
    for j in range(1, n+1):
        edelta[0][j] = edelta[0][j-1]+1
        for i in range(1, m+1):
            if u[i-1] == v[j-1]:
                same_char = 0
            else:
                same_char = 1

            edelta[i][j] = min(
                edelta[i-1][j]+1,
                edelta[i][j-1]+1,
                edelta[i-1][j-1]+same_char
            )
    return edelta
```

I get this message in vscode from pylance for `edelta[0][0] = 0`:

```
Argument of type "Literal[0]" cannot be assigned to parameter "__s" of type "slice" in function "__setitem__"
  "Literal[0]" is incompatible with "slice"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

and this message in PyCharm:

```
Unexpected type(s): (int, int) Possible type(s): (SupportsIndex, None) (slice, Iterable[None])
```

Comment: Is this really all of the code, enough to cause this error, or did you leave out code that comes after the error line?

Comment: This was enough to cause the message. But i will update the whole code and some more informations.

Comment: What are u and v? That can really change things. I get a different error with the first values I passed it. And your error messages are saying something is the wrong type.

Comment: @KennyOstrom u and v are strings. In the context of bioinformatics, they are DNA sequences